# Not able to rendered css file content when use as a local file but it is working when used from url itself

Tags: html, css

I want to use font-awesome.min.css file which was downloaded on my local system.

I am trying to use it but expected results not rendered. but if i use "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" then expected results rendered .

may i know why it is happening like this ?

I dont want to hit the url i just want to use file from local path.

Comment: open network tab and check if the CSS file was indeed downloaded ? if it was downloaded fine - then verify the contents by comparing with the actual file

Comment: That stylesheet refers font files in the form of `src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');`, using relative URLs. Relative URLs in stylesheets are resolved using the stylesheet URL as the base URL, so the font files are now looked for “locally” as well. You would need to download all of those font files and place them in the same folder structure for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have the font file for fontawesome, in my case, it's named
[fontawesome-webfont.woff2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtBKZ.png)
Placed in a fonts folder besides your folder that contains the fontawesome css